# How can I access command options in separate files?

Tags: node.js, module, command-line-interface, global, node-commander

I'm using [commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js) to specify some commands and options for my global node module in the `index.js` file of the project (like shown in the [example](https://github.com/tj/commander.js#option-parsing)).

I know that I can easily check if a command was used by using the following code:

```
if (program.peppers) {
  console.log('-peppers was used')
}
```

But how can I check those properties in other files? I've already tried exporting `program` and requiring it in those other files, but it doesn't seem to work.

Let's say I want to check if an option was used in a different file than in the one in which I've defined them. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the parsed program to the files/functions that need the parsed arguments or you can export the parsed arguments `program` instance

File `index.js`

```
var program = require('./program');

if (program.peppers) {
  console.log('-peppers was used')
}
```

File `program.js`

```
var program = require('commander');

program
  .version('0.0.1')
  .option('-p, --peppers', 'Add peppers')
  .option('-P, --pineapple', 'Add pineapple')
  .option('-b, --bbq-sauce', 'Add bbq sauce')
  .option('-c, --cheese [type]', 'Add the specified type of cheese [marble]', 'marble')
  .parse(process.argv);

module.exports = program;
```

Invoking `index.js` from command line:

```
> node index.js -p
```

Yields the output

```
-peppers was used
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I've already tried that. I've required the `program.js` file in one of my binaries in the module and as soon as I've tried to run the binary, the help showed up in the terminal. Doesn't make any sense, I know.

I'm also aware that the help pops up by default when calling the main command, but I'm not trying to call the main command, but rather a subcommand.

Comment: Found out how it works! You just need to require a new "commander" instance for each binary.

Comment: Hey @LeonardLamprecht I'm facing a similar problem. Would you mind explaining how you solved it?